# WPF - Mandatory 1-second loading time

Tags: c#, wpf

I started converting a WinForms application of mine over to WPF, and there was one major issue I noticed right off the bat: even on a completely blank WPF project, the application will take roughly a second to open, whereas even heavy/intense WinForms applications I've written start up instantly or with no noticeable delay. Is this a global issue, or is it just me?  If the former, is there any way to circumvent this? I find it incredibly annoying.

I apologise if this is a duplicate question (since it seems like something really basic), but I can't find any information on this.

Comment: How did you resolve problem of code-behind logic from `WinFroms` to WPF MvvM `ViewModel`?

Comment: A profiler is the right tool to diagnose this. We cannot do this for you.